# Upgrading elasticsearch: what is the state of "types" in version 7?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am in the process of upgrading Elasticsearch. I upgraded elasticsearch from `6.8` to `7.17` and I upgraded the javascript client to `@elastic/elasticsearch 7.17.0`. I then deleted my old indices, put the mappings in place and tried to reindex the data coming from another database.

Now I am struggling with the current state of types in elasticsearch 7.17. I know that an index can only have one type of document and it looks like the `type` parameter of the javascript client is deprecated, but it still seems to be required. When I make a call to client.index() it complains about a missing type parameter:

```
ConfigurationError: Missing required parameter: type
```

And the error stack points to this block of code:

```
    await client.index({
      index: indexName,
      id: obj.id,
      body: obj.body,
    });
```

My mappings look like this:

```
{
  "author_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "articleCount" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        }
        // ,,,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Should I still be specifying the type? Why does the client require it when its deprecated? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `type` with `_doc` and it should work as type is deprecated but you still need to give the `_doc` placeholder in the API calls.

Comment: Hmm, the examples in the client documentation don't include a type either. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/7.17/update_examples.html

But you're right: `client.index({ index, type: '_doc', body })` seems to work.

Comment: @Stefan great you found in the doc and able to fix issue, please upvote and accept answer, Thanks in advance

Comment: I will accept the answer because it worked, but I did not find it in the docs. Actually the opposite, the examples in the docs show no mention of using `type: '_doc'`.